# Footer not showing because image position set to relative

Tags: html, css

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grundysf/gksSy/21/)

If I remove the css below, everything shows fine. Without it the footer takes over the entire page blocking out everything.

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
.image .text {
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
    left:55px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Problem is without that code I can't get my overlay text to display on my images. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: try this way: [demo](http://jsbin.com/OJoyEFI/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear:both` to `#footer`;

```
#footer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 850px;
    background: #444;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: always have a class `.clearfix{clear:both}` in your css and call it as and when you want rather than adding `clear:both` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try `clear: both` to footer.

```
#footer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 850px;
    background: #444;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```